# How can I read the manifest of an Android apk file using C# .Net?

Tags: c#, android, .net, android-manifest, apk

I have a .net webservice that should be aware of the version of an `apk` file that is in one of its folders. I know `apktool` but I need to read the manifest of the `apk` by my .net webserice.

How can I do that? do you know any sample code in c# for decoding and reading the manifest of the `apk` file?

**Unziping `apk` and deciding the manifest file is my main problem**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8727925/1292203 have a look at the following post is this fruitful to you

Comment: @UsmanKurd No I have read it. Its assumption is that the manifest is extracted and decoded using apktool.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I used [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Default.aspx) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4761689/779408) and created a .Net version.

```
string apkPath = "C:\\app.apk";
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream zip = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipInputStream(File.OpenRead(apkPath));
var filestream = new FileStream(apkPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile zipfile = new ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipFile(filestream);
ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry item;


 while ((item = zip.GetNextEntry()) != null)
 {
    if (item.Name == "AndroidManifest.xml")
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[50 * 1024];

        Stream strm = zipfile.GetInputStream(item);
        int size = strm.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

        using (BinaryReader s = new BinaryReader(strm))
        {
            byte[] bytes2 = new byte[size];
            Array.Copy(bytes, bytes2, size);
            AndroidDecompress decompress = new AndroidDecompress();
            content = decompress.decompressXML(bytes);
        }
     }
  }
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for AndroidDecompress
/// </summary>
public class AndroidDecompress
{
    private string result = "";
    // decompressXML -- Parse the 'compressed' binary form of Android XML docs 
    // such as for AndroidManifest.xml in .apk files
    public static int endDocTag = 0x00100101;
    public static int startTag = 0x00100102;
    public static int endTag = 0x00100103;
    public string decompressXML(byte[] xml)
    {
        // Compressed XML file/bytes starts with 24x bytes of data,
        // 9 32 bit words in little endian order (LSB first):
        //   0th word is 03 00 08 00
        //   3rd word SEEMS TO BE:  Offset at then of StringTable
        //   4th word is: Number of strings in string table
        // WARNING: Sometime I indiscriminently display or refer to word in 
        //   little endian storage format, or in integer format (ie MSB first).
        int numbStrings = LEW(xml, 4 * 4);

        // StringIndexTable starts at offset 24x, an array of 32 bit LE offsets
        // of the length/string data in the StringTable.
        int sitOff = 0x24;  // Offset of start of StringIndexTable

        // StringTable, each string is represented with a 16 bit little endian 
        // character count, followed by that number of 16 bit (LE) (Unicode) chars.
        int stOff = sitOff + numbStrings * 4;  // StringTable follows StrIndexTable

        // XMLTags, The XML tag tree starts after some unknown content after the
        // StringTable.  There is some unknown data after the StringTable, scan
        // forward from this point to the flag for the start of an XML start tag.
        int xmlTagOff = LEW(xml, 3 * 4);  // Start from the offset in the 3rd word.
        // Scan forward until we find the bytes: 0x02011000(x00100102 in normal int)
        for (int ii = xmlTagOff; ii < xml.Length - 4; ii += 4)
        {
            if (LEW(xml, ii) == startTag)
            {
                xmlTagOff = ii; break;
            }
        } // end of hack, scanning for start of first start tag

        // XML tags and attributes:
        // Every XML start and end tag consists of 6 32 bit words:
        //   0th word: 02011000 for startTag and 03011000 for endTag 
        //   1st word: a flag?, like 38000000
        //   2nd word: Line of where this tag appeared in the original source file
        //   3rd word: FFFFFFFF ??
        //   4th word: StringIndex of NameSpace name, or FFFFFFFF for default NS
        //   5th word: StringIndex of Element Name
        //   (Note: 01011000 in 0th word means end of XML document, endDocTag)

        // Start tags (not end tags) contain 3 more words:
        //   6th word: 14001400 meaning?? 
        //   7th word: Number of Attributes that follow this tag(follow word 8th)
        //   8th word: 00000000 meaning??

        // Attributes consist of 5 words: 
        //   0th word: StringIndex of Attribute Name's Namespace, or FFFFFFFF
        //   1st word: StringIndex of Attribute Name
        //   2nd word: StringIndex of Attribute Value, or FFFFFFF if ResourceId used
        //   3rd word: Flags?
        //   4th word: str ind of attr value again, or ResourceId of value

        // TMP, dump string table to tr for debugging
        //tr.addSelect("strings", null);
        //for (int ii=0; ii<numbStrings; ii++) {
        //  // Length of string starts at StringTable plus offset in StrIndTable
        //  String str = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, ii);
        //  tr.add(String.valueOf(ii), str);
        //}
        //tr.parent();

        // Step through the XML tree element tags and attributes
        int off = xmlTagOff;
        int indent = 0;
        int startTagLineNo = -2;
        while (off < xml.Length)
        {
            int tag0 = LEW(xml, off);
            //int tag1 = LEW(xml, off+1*4);
            int lineNo = LEW(xml, off + 2 * 4);
            //int tag3 = LEW(xml, off+3*4);
            int nameNsSi = LEW(xml, off + 4 * 4);
            int nameSi = LEW(xml, off + 5 * 4);

            if (tag0 == startTag)
            { // XML START TAG
                int tag6 = LEW(xml, off + 6 * 4);  // Expected to be 14001400
                int numbAttrs = LEW(xml, off + 7 * 4);  // Number of Attributes to follow
                //int tag8 = LEW(xml, off+8*4);  // Expected to be 00000000
                off += 9 * 4;  // Skip over 6+3 words of startTag data
                String name = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, nameSi);
                //tr.addSelect(name, null);
                startTagLineNo = lineNo;

                // Look for the Attributes

                string sb = "";
                for (int ii = 0; ii < numbAttrs; ii++)
                {
                    int attrNameNsSi = LEW(xml, off);  // AttrName Namespace Str Ind, or FFFFFFFF
                    int attrNameSi = LEW(xml, off + 1 * 4);  // AttrName String Index
                    int attrValueSi = LEW(xml, off + 2 * 4); // AttrValue Str Ind, or FFFFFFFF
                    int attrFlags = LEW(xml, off + 3 * 4);
                    int attrResId = LEW(xml, off + 4 * 4);  // AttrValue ResourceId or dup AttrValue StrInd
                    off += 5 * 4;  // Skip over the 5 words of an attribute

                    String attrName = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, attrNameSi);
                    String attrValue = attrValueSi != -1
                      ? compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, attrValueSi)
                      : /*"resourceID 0x" + */attrResId.ToString();
                    sb += " " + attrName + "=\"" + attrValue + "\"";
                    //tr.add(attrName, attrValue);
                }
                prtIndent(indent, "<" + name + sb + ">");
                indent++;

            }
            else if (tag0 == endTag)
            { // XML END TAG
                indent--;
                off += 6 * 4;  // Skip over 6 words of endTag data
                String name = compXmlString(xml, sitOff, stOff, nameSi);
                prtIndent(indent, "</" + name + ">  \r\n"/*+"(line " + startTagLineNo + "-" + lineNo + ")"*/);
                //tr.parent();  // Step back up the NobTree

            }
            else if (tag0 == endDocTag)
            {  // END OF XML DOC TAG
                break;

            }
            else
            {
                prt("  Unrecognized tag code '" + tag0.ToString("X")
                  + "' at offset " + off);
                break;
            }
        } // end of while loop scanning tags and attributes of XML tree
        //prt("    end at offset " + off);


        return result;
    } // end of decompressXML


    public String compXmlString(byte[] xml, int sitOff, int stOff, int strInd)
    {
        if (strInd < 0) return null;
        int strOff = stOff + LEW(xml, sitOff + strInd * 4);
        return compXmlStringAt(xml, strOff);
    }


    public static String spaces = "                                             ";
    public void prtIndent(int indent, String str)
    {
        prt(spaces.Substring(0, Math.Min(indent * 2, spaces.Length)) + str);
    }

    private void prt(string p)
    {
        result += p;
    }


    // compXmlStringAt -- Return the string stored in StringTable format at
    // offset strOff.  This offset points to the 16 bit string length, which 
    // is followed by that number of 16 bit (Unicode) chars.
    public String compXmlStringAt(byte[] arr, int strOff)
    {
        int strLen = arr[strOff + 1] << 8 & 0xff00 | arr[strOff] & 0xff;
        byte[] chars = new byte[strLen];
        for (int ii = 0; ii < strLen; ii++)
        {
            chars[ii] = arr[strOff + 2 + ii * 2];
        }


        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(chars);  // Hack, just use 8 byte chars
    } // end of compXmlStringAt


    // LEW -- Return value of a Little Endian 32 bit word from the byte array
    //   at offset off.
    public int LEW(byte[] arr, int off)
    {
        return (int)(arr[off + 3] << 24 & 0xff000000 | arr[off + 2] << 16 & 0xff0000 | arr[off + 1] << 8 & 0xff00 | arr[off] & 0xFF);
    } // end of LEW

}
```

Comment: your `using (BinaryReader s = new BinaryReader(strm))` line is obsolete, since you don't use s.

Comment: ` byte[] bytes = new byte[50 * 1024];` how do you know it will never go beyond 50 KB ??

Comment: The above code is not working for android latest version.any one have idea?

Comment: @AkramKhan I've found that https://github.com/hylander0/Iteedee.ApkReader/pull/13/commits/5c48dfbe09fce9669e4bb54d925c62f26f88d5c4 fixes this issue

Comment: Hey, the library and code above work for smaller size APKs, but when I pass a APK of like 30mb it says "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

I have created a .NET library that parses/reads the **androidManifest.xml** file data and cross references the **Resources.arsc** for reference Id values (so you don't have to).

#### [Parse APK Manifest with C# .NET with Iteedee.ApkReader](https://github.com/hylander0/Iteedee.ApkReader)

> The primary goal of this library is to parse Android Application package **meta-data**. There are many scenarios where you might need to glean information about your android package, specifically in **continuous integration** setups.

After decompressing the file, all that is required is passing the needed byte array objects into the library's method:

```
ApkReader apkReader = new ApkReader();
ApkInfo info = apkReader.extractInfo(manifestData, resourcesData);
```

The `APKInfo` object supplies:

- *Package Name*
- *Version Name*
- *Version Code*
- *App Has Icon Check*
- *All (dpi types) of the App Icons Found*
- *Permissions*
- *Screen Density Support Configuration*

Comment: Thank you for writing the lib, but I must say, it could've written better.

Comment: This is library is a manual port of a java implementation.  There are some issues with the library as @n3verLieMe mentioned.  YMMV. You can see the issue list on [github](https://github.com/hylander0/Iteedee.ApkReader)

Comment: Is there any fork for this on Java/Kotlin?

Comment: Updated link to point to the github location

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not going to add any particular feature to the existing ones.

But I was unsatisfied by the readability and *idiomaticity* of the ported Java code.

So I started from the code published by @Bobs and refactored it until I was satisfied from the result. But, aside from my OCD, it is basically the same thing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

// ReSharper disable CommentTypo

namespace Utils
{
    /// <summary> Unpacks and reads data from a compressed apk manifest file. </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Code coming from:
    /// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997163/how-can-i-read-the-manifest-of-an-android-apk-file-using-c-sharp-net/22314629
    /// </remarks>
    public class AndroidManifestReader
    {
        // Parses the 'compressed' binary form of Android XML docs 
        // such as for AndroidManifest.binaryXml in .apk files
        private const int END_DOC_TAG = 0x00100101;
        private const int START_TAG = 0x00100102;
        private const int END_TAG = 0x00100103;

        // StringIndexTable starts at offset 24x, an array of 32 bit LE offsets
        // of the length/string data in the StringTable.
        private const int STRING_INDEX_TABLE_OFFSET = 0x24;

        private readonly byte[] _xml;

        private XDocument _manifest;

        /// <summary>Reads and returns the uncompressed Xml Manifest</summary>
        public XDocument Manifest => _manifest ?? (_manifest = ReadManifest());

        public AndroidManifestReader(byte[] xml)
        {
            _xml = xml ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(xml));
        }

        private XDocument ReadManifest()
        {
            var result = new XDocument();
            result.Add(new XElement("root"));

            var tagStack = new Stack<XElement>();
            tagStack.Push(result.Root);

            var tagOffset = FindStartOfTags();
            while (tagOffset < _xml.Length)
            {
                var tagCode = BitConverter.ToInt32(_xml, tagOffset);
                switch (tagCode)
                {
                    case START_TAG:
                        tagOffset += ReadStartTag(tagOffset, out var startTag);
                        tagStack.Peek().Add(startTag);
                        tagStack.Push(startTag);
                        break;
                    case END_TAG:
                        var expectedTagName = tagStack.Peek().Name.LocalName;
                        tagOffset += ReadEndTag(tagOffset, expectedTagName);
                        tagStack.Pop();
                        break;
                    case END_DOC_TAG:
                        goto manifest_read;
                    default:
                        goto manifest_read;
                }
            }

            manifest_read:
            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>Reads a start tag and returns the number of consumed bytes.</summary>
        /// <param name="offset"></param>
        /// <param name="element"></param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// XML tags and attributes:
        /// Every XML start and end tag consists of 6 32 bit words:
        ///   0th word: 02011000 for startTag, 03011000 for endTag, 01011000 for end of document
        ///   1st word: a flag?, like 38000000
        ///   2nd word: Line of where this tag appeared in the original source file
        ///   3rd word: FFFFFFFF ??
        ///   4th word: StringIndex of NameSpace name, or FFFFFFFF for default NS
        ///   5th word: StringIndex of Element Name
        /// 
        /// Start tags (not end tags) contain 3 more words:
        ///   6th word: 14001400 meaning?? 
        ///   7th word: Number of Attributes that follow this tag(follow word 8th)
        ///   8th word: 00000000 meaning??
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns>The number of bytes consumed by the tag.</returns>
        private int ReadStartTag(int offset, out XElement element)
        {
            const int startTagDataSize = 9 * 4;
            element = new XElement(ReadTagName(offset));
            var bytesConsumed = startTagDataSize;

            var attributesCount = BitConverter.ToInt32(_xml, offset + 7 * 4);

            for (var attrIdx = 0; attrIdx < attributesCount; attrIdx++)
            {
                bytesConsumed += ReadAttribute(offset + bytesConsumed, out var attr);
                element.Add(attr);
            }

            return bytesConsumed;
        }

        /// <summary>Reads an attribute starting at the specified offset,
        /// and returns the consumed bytes count.</summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Attributes consist of 5 words: 
        ///   0th word: StringIndex of Attribute Name's Namespace, or FFFFFFFF
        ///   1st word: StringIndex of Attribute Name
        ///   2nd word: StringIndex of Attribute Value, or FFFFFFF if ResourceId used
        ///   3rd word: Flags?
        ///   4th word: str ind of attr value again, or ResourceId of value
        /// </remarks>
        private int ReadAttribute(int offset, out XAttribute attribute)
        {
            var attributeNameStringIndex = BitConverter.ToInt32(_xml, offset + 1 * 4);
            var attrName = RetrieveFromStringTable(attributeNameStringIndex);

            var attributeValueStringIndex = BitConverter.ToInt32(_xml, offset + 2 * 4);
            // AttrValue ResourceId or dup AttrValue StrInd
            var attributeResourceId = BitConverter.ToInt32(_xml, offset + 4 * 4);

            var attrValue = attributeValueStringIndex >= 0
                ? RetrieveFromStringTable(attributeValueStringIndex)
                : attributeResourceId.ToString();

            attribute = new XAttribute(attrName, attrValue);
            return 20;
        }

        private int ReadEndTag(int tagOffset, string expectedTagName)
        {
            var tagName = ReadTagName(tagOffset);
            // Skip over 6 words of endTag data
            return tagName == expectedTagName
                ? 6 * 4
                : throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    $"Malformed XML: expecting {expectedTagName} but found {tagName}");
        }

        private string ReadTagName(int tagOffset)
        {
            var nameIndexOffset = tagOffset + 5 * 4;
            var nameStringIndex = BitConverter.ToInt32(_xml, nameIndexOffset);
            return RetrieveFromStringTable(nameStringIndex);
        }

        private int GetStringTableOffset()
        {
            // Compressed XML file/bytes starts with 24x bytes of data,
            // 9 32 bit words in little endian order (LSB first):
            //   0th word is 03 00 08 00
            //   3rd word SEEMS TO BE:  Offset at then of StringTable
            //   4th word is: Number of strings in string table
            var stringsCount = BitConverter.ToInt32(_xml, 4 * 4);
            return STRING_INDEX_TABLE_OFFSET + stringsCount * 4;
        }

        /// <summary> Return the string stored in StringTable format at
        /// offset strOff.  This offset points to the 16 bit string length, which 
        /// is followed by that number of 16 bit (Unicode) chars. </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string RetrieveFromStringTable(int strInd)
        {
            if (strInd < 0) return null;

            // StringTable, each string is represented with a 16 bit little endian 
            // character count, followed by that number of 16 bit (LE) (Unicode) chars.
            // StringTable follows StrIndexTable
            var stringOffset = GetStringTableOffset() +
                               BitConverter.ToInt32(_xml, STRING_INDEX_TABLE_OFFSET + strInd * 4);
            var stringLength = BitConverter.ToInt16(_xml, stringOffset);
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(_xml, stringOffset + 2, stringLength * 2);
        }

        /// <summary> The XML tag tree starts after some unknown content after the StringTable.
        /// There is some unknown data after the StringTable, scan forward from this point
        /// to the flag for the start of an XML start tag. </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        internal int FindStartOfTags()
        {
            // 12 is the index of the word containing the base offset of the xml tree.
            var xmlTagOffset = BitConverter.ToInt32(_xml, 12);

            for (var offset = xmlTagOffset; offset < _xml.Length - 4; offset += 4)
            {
                if (BitConverter.ToInt32(_xml, offset) == START_TAG) return offset;
            }

            return xmlTagOffset;
        }
    }
}
```

```
var manifest = new AndroidManifestReader(bytes).Manifest;
```